# iOS In-App Purchase: Managing auto-renewal subscription of different families

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app

In our application, we support 3 types of subscription like:

Silver Monthly auto-Subscription   price: 9.99$/monthly
Gold Monthly auto-Subscription     price: 15.99$/monthly
Platinum Monthly auto-Subscription price: 24.99$/monthly

All this subscription belong to the different family and each family has only one type of Subscription that is monthly -silver, gold, and platinum.

we have some query to understand the auto-renewal flow, which I listed:

Can user switch between auto-renewal product families from iTunes Manage Subscription / from Application? (in our case b/w silver<-> gold<->platinum).

our aim is to keep anyone subscription at a single time and give user option to upgrade and downgrade their subscription plan.

Are we violating any Apple policy by managing 3 auto-renewal subscriptions in our application of same time period (1 month)and different price?